# ArrayList Retrieve First and Last Result without Sorting ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, netbeans, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of String, and I would like to retrieve the first and last result of the names after calculating the order of alphabets. Below is my code snippet:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(20);
    list.add("Charles Darwin");
    list.add("Albert Einstein");
    list.add("Issac Newton");
    list.add("Tony Hoare");
    list.add("Grace Hopper");
    list.add("Edgar Dijkstra");
    list.add("Ada Lovelace");
    list.add("Charles Babbage");
    list.add("Stephen Hawking");

String biggest = "";
            String smallest = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String first = list.get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                    String second = list.get(j);
                    if (!first.equalsIgnoreCase(second)) {
                        if (first.compareToIgnoreCase(second)>0){
                            biggest=first;
                        }
                        if (first.compareToIgnoreCase(second)<0){
                            smallest=first;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
System.out.println(biggest);
            System.out.println(smallest);
```

I am able to retrieve every value for comparison, however, the results are always showing Stephen Hawking as the biggest and smallest.

My desired results are Ada Lovelace as biggest and Tony Hoare as smallest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional statements seem to wrong.

```
                       if (first.compareToIgnoreCase(second)>0){
                            biggest=first;
                        }
                        if (first.compareToIgnoreCase(second)<0){
                            smallest=first;
                        }
```

You're comparing the element in the outer loop to the element in the inner loop. You never make a comparison against the `biggest` and `smallest`.

This should help you find the biggest and smallest String in your list.

```
 String biggest = list.get(0);
 String smallest = list.get(0);
 for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if(list.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(biggest) > 0)
       biggest = list.get(i);
    if(list.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(smallest) < 0)
       smallest = list.get(i);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use Collections.min() and max() as stated in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Collections.min / max

Comment: how can I printout the results after `Collections.min(list)`?

Comment: String min = Collections.min(list)

Answer (score 1):

are your required to use `List` ? You might want to see `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html`. then you can use first() and last() method

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Java, but I can still recognize multiple issues with this code:

- Why are you hard coding initial capacity to 20?
- Why are you using indexed loops instead of for each?
- Why are you using a nested loop to find min/max?
- Use else instead of running the same comparison twice
- If first always equals second biggest and smallest will remain uninitiated
- And last, and directly dressing your question, all your code does is finding if the last item is greater & smaller than **any** of the other items in the list, not all of them, since you keep ignoring previous findings and not using biggest/smallest as a condition in any of your comparisons.